# Substitution for deprecated axis.ticks.margin in ggplot2 2.0

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

When using `axis.ticks.margin` in ggplot2 2.0, I got a Warning message:

> `axis.ticks.margin` is deprecated. Please set `margin` property  of `axis.text` instead.

I thought I could try `axis.text.margin` but I got another warning saying it was an invalid function. The release notes say:

> The theme setting `axis.ticks.margin` has been deprecated: now use the margin property of axis.ticks.

So where is the margin setting now?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the ggplot 2.0 doc on [`theme`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/theme.html):

> axis.text
>
> tick labels along axes (element_text; inherits from text)

This should be in an `element_text` element. Its [doc](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/element_text.html) points to function `margin`. Something along those lines should work:

```
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin=margin(5,5,10,5,"pt")),
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin=margin(5,5,10,5,"pt")))
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems we have to adjust the margins of x and y individually. For x, only top and bottom work and for y, only right and left work. It gives us more power to adjust them delicately but is more complicated compared to the earlier versions.

Comment: @Chuanxin I don't think you have to set them separately.  Just do `axis.text = element_text(...)`

Comment: @C8H10N4O2, They do need to be set separately as the answer and Chuanxwin's comment both note

Answer (score 0):

With `axis.ticks.margin` deprecated, the only option is to expand the y axis - otherwise you're only increasing the space between the axis text and the axis ticks:

```
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0.1))
```